# ATR Trailing Stop Loss Indicator in TradingView

Tags: python, pine-script, algorithmic-trading, technical-indicator, pine-script-v4

I was going through below pinescript code of ATR Trailing Stop loss indicator and was trying to code it in Python. I'm facing difficulty understanding below lines.

```
 Prev = H,barssince(close>H and close>close[1])
 TS = iff(cum(1)<16,close,iff( close > H and close>close[1],H,Prev))
```

Value H gives you the highest value (highest(high-Mult*atr(Atr),Hhv)). On next line, barsince function is giving the count of bars/candles when conditions were met.

What does the complete statement H,barssince signifies? I mean what value will be stored in Prev.

Also what cum(1) function does?

```
//@version=4
study("ATR Trailing Stoploss",overlay=true)
Atr = 3   // input(defval=5,title="Atr Period",minval=1,maxval=500)
Hhv= 10  // input(defval=10,title="HHV Period",minval=1,maxval=500)
Mult= 2.5 // input(defval=2.5,title="Multiplier",minval=0.1)
Barcolor=input(true,title="Barcolor")

H = highest(high-Mult*atr(Atr),Hhv)  
Prev = H,barssince(close>H and close>close[1])
TS = iff(cum(1)<16,close,iff( close > H and close>close[1],H,Prev))

Color=iff(close>TS,color.green,iff(close<TS,color.red,color.black))
barcolor(Barcolor? Color:na)

plot(TS,color=Color,linewidth=3,title="ATR Trailing Stoploss")

Buy=crossover(close,TS)
Sell=crossunder(close,TS)

plotshape(Buy,"BUY", shape.labelup, location.belowbar, color.green, 
text="BUY",textcolor=color.black)
plotshape(Sell,"SELL", shape.labeldown, location.abovebar, color.red, 
text="SELL",textcolor=color.black)

alertcondition(Buy, "Buy Signal", "Buy ATR Trailing Stoploss")
alertcondition(Sell, "Sell Signal", "Sell ATR Trailing Stoploss")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can place more than one statement on a line by using the comma (,) as a separator.

So, `Prev = H,barssince(close>H and close>close[1])` is actually;

```
Prev = H
barssince(close>H and close>close[1])  // Return value is lost
```

I modified the script and removed the variable `Prev`, such that:

```
H = highest(high-Mult*atr(Atr),Hhv)  
TS = iff(cum(1)<16,close,iff( close > H and close>close[1],H,H))
```

You can see the result in thechart on the bottom. The one on the top is the original script. As you can see, there is no difference.

[image]

`cum(1)` is the cumulative sum. It will start from 1, and add 1 to the sum on each bar. So, it will count the number of bars starting from 1, unlike `bar_index`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @vitruvius for simplifying the logic and explaining how the cum() function works.

If I look at below code.. second expression in TS will always evaluate to H irrespective of iff condition is true or false. So, we can simply reduce it to H.

```
x = iff( close > H and close>close[1],H,H) = H
TS = iff(cum(1)<16,close,H)
```

Comment: Actually it will evaluate to close for the first 15 bars and after that it will always evaluate to H. If the first bars are ever to be used then the number 16 should be replaced with the input periods used  :-)